# Is localhost.mydomain.com a legal name which could legitmately point to something other than 127.0.0.1?

Tags: domain-name-system

Is localhost.mydomain.com a legal name which could legitimately point to something other than 127.0.0.1?

It is certainly problematic in some circumstances (my example is the AWS ECS agent (Go SDK) which is appending a search path learned from DHCP options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it *legal?* Sure. No laws exist against it.

Is it *syntactically correct?* Sure, it doesn’t break any RFCs.

Is it probable that someone will add a record for `localhost.mydomain.com`? You’ll have to contact the US company MyDomain, located in Massachusetts, and ask them if they have plans to use that hostname within the domain `mydomain.com` that they’ve owned since roughly 1998.

All in all, it’s no more likely to cause a problem as any other syntactically correct usage of a domain and hostname *that you don’t have control over.*

Comment: Yes that was my impression. Thanks.